# One CDN with origin pull and two servers

Tags: cdn

I have two dedicated servers serving the same website. I am thinking of adding CDN to it... Since the CDN will pull the contents from server, my concern is won't it have any naming conflicts ??? To clarify more precisely:

- Server1 and Server2 has real time sync, every files syncs between them.
- If I add CDN with Origin Pull, CDN will pull all the defined files to it..
- The files that CDN is going to pull would be same from both Servers, same name, same extensions like a.css, b.js, c.png.
- Now, will it create conflict or it'll just remove the old content and keep the fresh pull ?

Even if it replaces the new content with old ones, my bandwidth seems to be going waste for puling from both servers.... ain't it ?

Comment: Have you test Varnish solution ?

Answer (score 1):

If the CDN is well designed, it'll pull the content once. If the content is mirrored on both servers and there's a load balancer of some sort between them, then the content will only be pulled when it goes "stale".

Your content, when it gets served to your clients, needs to be served through the CDN, not your server.

Comment: thanks for the insight @Kyros, Yes the static content would be served via CDN, but looking for solution as you mentioned `Well Designed CDN`